# Loading routes according to HTTP_HOST in MVC4

Tags: c#, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a multi-tenant MVC4 website in which I want to set up the the *RouteTable* according incoming host and domain name eg *www.domain1.com*, *www.domain2.com* and *www.domain3.co.uk* could have one or more additional values appended to the route table according to the host and domain anem.

The DNS server has been set up with a number of distinct zones with hosts, and I'm using IIS7 as a 'custom web server' rather than using Visual Studio 2012 Development Server so that I get the correct HTTP_HOST value available to me in the *Request* variable.

The problem I have with IIS7 is that to the value of HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] is not available if you try to call it in the *RegisterRoutes* method where all the other route mapping is done.

The main thing I need to do is determine at some point in the request pipeline the the value that will eventually end up in the HTTP_HOST server variable .  That value needs storing and the route table appropriately updated before it gets used.

Will it need an Http Module, Http Handler, Action Filter or somesuch? Or is there some other place in the MVC pipeline that I can do this.

Crispin

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in support for routing based on host that I'm aware of, but you can create a Route subclass that pulls the host value in. Here's an example:

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-domain-routing.aspx

That's written for MVC3, but should work fine in MVC4.